# How to set tabbar image color ios button?

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton, uitabbar

i create a 4 button like tabbar , but image show as colored ,i need show images as like tabbar image color (gray) .


Thanks

Comment: Your question is ambiguous please explain it correctly.

Comment: i create a button like tabbar i want show image in button like tab bar controller showing

Comment: So you have to created as many buttons as you want in tab bar and after tapping on it change the color of that  button and other will come on their previous state

Comment: Created gray version of your image and set it in selected mode.

Comment: If you have 4 buttons then you should have 8 images 4 for selected state 4 for unselected state. And try whichever you see appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Set the icon to the tabbar like this

```
self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
```

Don't use

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage];
```

because then the image will not be automatically styled to the default tabbar style

You just need to set the image mask (gray, 1 color image with the transparency), not the complete image. According to the documentation

> A custom icon that you provide for a toolbar, navigation bar, or tab
>   bar is also known as a template image, because iOS uses it as a mask
>   to create the icon you see in your app. It is not necessary to create
>   a full-color template image.

See for more info:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1